# Binary Search and Sorting - CS50 Find pset3

Tags: c, binary-search, cs50

I'm trying to implement a binary search after doing a selection sort for CS50, pset3 find.

I feel that my logic is correct, but I don't know where my code is wrong. Below is my code.

[Error List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LlBn.png)

```
#include <cs50.h>

#include "helpers.h"

#define RANGE 65536

/**
 * Returns true if value is in array of n values, else false.
 */
bool search(int value, int values[], int n)
{
    // TODO: implement a searching algorithm
    //binary search
    int midpoint =  ((0 + (n-1))/2);

    while (n  > 0)
    {
        if (value == values[midpoint])
        {
        return true;
        }
        else if (value < values[midpoint]){
        midpoint = ((0 + (midpoint-1))/2);
        }
        else if  (value > values[midpoint]){
        midpoint = (((midpoint+1) + (n-1))/2);
        }
        if (value != values[midpoint])
        {
        return false;
        }
    }
   return false;
}

/**
 * Sorts array of n values.
 */
void sort(int values[], int n)
{
    // TODO: implement a sorting algorithm
    //selection sort
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int min = i;

        for (int j = i+1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if(values [j]< values[min])
            {
              min = j;
            }
            if(min != i)
            {
              int exchange = values [min];
              values [min] = values [i];
              values [i] = exchange;
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Basically, I think my logic is mostly correct, but again, I'm not too sure. I am still a beginner so I get caught up in the simplest errors sometimes. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Start with the first error that is reported.  Fix it. Look to see if any of the next errors are also fixable, but they may be consequences of the first error.  When you’ve fixed what you can, recompile, working on the remaining errors in the same methodical fashion.

Answer (score 1):

The function is wrong.

For example it can be executed infinitely. Let's assume that `n` is equal to 1. In this case initially `midpoint`

```
int midpoint =  ((0 + (n-1))/2);
```

will be set to 0. If `value` is less than `values[0]`  then again due to this if statement

```
    else if (value < values[midpoint]){
    midpoint = ((0 + (midpoint-1))/2);
    }
```

`midpoint` will be set to 0. And this part of the function will be repeated again and again.

Also the calculation of `midpoint` in this if statement

```
    else if  (value > values[midpoint]){
    midpoint = (((midpoint+1) + (n-1))/2);
                                ^^^^^
    }
```

is wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your note. Now, This is something I noticed, but I'm still having a hard time understanding how to fix the problem. If I set the while loop condition to n>1, then it should solve the problem, but it doesn't--am I not setting the proper conditions?

Comment: @JamesKwonLee You should close this question and ask a new question because relative your new updated code.